# In React - how to find out if a component is mounted at a node

Tags: reactjs

I have some code that may render a component:

```
ReactDOM.render(myComponent, domNode)
```

whether or not this is called depends on a user action.

Later I want to detect if myComponent was indeed rendered and if so remove it. Currently I am doing:

```
if domNode.childNodes.length > 0
 ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode(domNode)
```

What would be the React way of testing for a component existing in the tree? (Without using TestUtils).

Answer (score 3):

Assign a `ref` to `myComponent`

```
<myComponent ref="sapyC" />

if !domNode.refs.sapyC 
 ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode(domNode)
```

Comment: Thanks. In general this is useful for me. However; the catch in this case is  - how do I assigne a ref to a component when i am rendering it with ReactDOM.render rather than 'inline' with <myComponent>?

Comment: `ReactDom.render(<MyCustomComp ref="sapy"/>, document.getElementById('sapy') )`

Comment: FYI: You can skip the check to see if it was previously mounted. In that case `ReactDOM. unmountComponentAtNode` will just do nothing (and return false).